# react native how to get input when enter is clicked

Tags: react-native

how to get input when the user presses the enter key?
my current code will not wait, whenever user enter will save immediately, so only getting the first char or int.

```
<TextInput
              placeholder={placeholder}
              placeholderTextColor="#b1e5d3"
              style={externalStyle.home_input}
              // onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
              onChangeText={(text) => setinputtext(text)}
            />
```

setinputtext

```
  const setinputtext = (input) => {
if (resultdisplay) {
  onChangeText(input);
} else {
  console.log("setting input number stock", input);
  setNumStock(input);
  setaddbuttonactivity(false);
  setresultdisplay(true);
  setplaceholder("Search");
  setaddbuttondisplay("add");
  console.log(numStock, selectedStock);
  var message = selectedStock.concat(" is in your invested stock");
  ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(
    message,
    ToastAndroid.LONG,
    ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
    40,
    5
  );
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `onSubmitEditing` method as `onChangeText`. please look into the below code

```
   <TextInput
      placeholder={placeholder}
      placeholderTextColor="#b1e5d3"
      style={externalStyle.home_input}
      // onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
      onChangeText={(text) => setinputtext(text)}
      onSubmitEditing={({nativeEvent: {text}}) => {
        console.log('Text value on press enter: ', text);
        // Do your code here.
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the value in the state

`value={value}`

see in [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)